# Error when trying to fetch rows from mysql and using multi threading to process them

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading

Code that tries to read from mysql db and process them :

```
try:
    sema = threading.Semaphore(value=100)
    threads = []
    connection = pymysql.connect(host= host, user=user, passwd=pwd, db="Golden")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT query FROM golden_Queries");
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    while rows is not None:
        for line in rows:
            t = Thread(target=fetchAndStore, args=(line,))
            t.daemon = True
            threads.append(t)
        for t in threads:
            t.start()
        [t.join() for t in threads]
except Exception,e: 
    print str(e)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

fetchAndStore will then process these queries one by one. That module works fine.

Output :

```
Exception in thread Thread-82:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "fetchFromDB.py", line 59, in fetchAndStore
    query_string = urllib.urlencode(query)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1333, in urlencode
    raise TypeError
TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object

can't start new thread
```

Any help will be really nice :)

Comment: The error clearly complains about the line `query_string = urllib.urlencode(query)` in `fetchAndStore` which wasn't posted, nor is it related to multithreading. The error line shows `File "fetchFromDB.py", line 59, in fetchAndStore
    query_string = urllib.urlencode(query)`

Comment: Wonder how i missed that. Thanks.

Comment: ensue your query is string, and your error does not occur on the code you provided.